# Are control surfaces less effective at supersonic speeds?

Tags: supersonic, control-surfaces, shock-waves

I am unsure if this is correct but this is my current explanation:
Once past supersonic speeds, the larger the speed the larger the divot of air pressure around the plane. Because these divots can get so large at high speeds, control surfaces are ineffective due to the air not flowing close enough to them. When I say divots, I am referring to the "wavefronts" and "shock cone" around the aircraft. Image for reference (from Wikipedia):

[image: Mach cone]

Comment: No, in fact rockets and missiles requires small surfaces (see e.g. SpaceX's grid fins which are very effective on high speed). Air and its (static) kinetic energy are the same per volume (but it varies with altitude and temperature).

Comment: There may be less longitudinal stability due to (wave) pressure on the nose rather than significant loss of control surface authority.  Pressure differential within the "divot" (being a golfer, I like it) is measured in pounds per *square foot* (divide by 144 for psi). It may be significant at origin and worth study.  Early high speed rocket aircraft (the X series) had a tendency to lose stability, but these were flown in extremely thin atmosphere.  Loss of stability at higher speeds was known as "divergence".  Notice the build of the SR-71 was extremely stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Once past supersonic speeds, the larger the speed the larger the divot of air pressure around the plane.

There are no divots around the plane. Even at supersonic speeds air keeps on following the plane's contour just like at subsonic speeds. When the airplane comes, air just gets out of the way; at subsonic speeds air begins already well in front of the airplane to move away while at supersonic speeds it does it instantaneously via shock and compression waves.

No matter the speed, lift and drag always follow the well known relationships:

$\begin{cases}
L=½ \rho V² SC_l\\
D=½ \rho V² SC_d
\end{cases}$

so that, in general, the bigger the speed the bigger the aerodynamic forces.

Anyway both $C_l$ and $C_d$ also change with the speed. In particular, all the rest being the same:

- $C_d$ at supersonic speed is always bigger than at subsonic speed due to the [wave drag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_drag);
- $C_l$ at supersonic speed is lower than at subsonic speed with a ratio that, at least theoretically, for a thin airfoil is 4/2π.

So you're right that

> control surfaces effectiveness lowers at supersonic speeds

since $C_d$ is bigger and $C_l$ is lower but this is more than compensate for by the higher speed $V$.

Comment: One can measure the supersonic cone with Schlieren photography.  This has been done with rifle bullets.  The *angle* of the cone can be used to determine Mach number by the formula M = 1/(sine cone angle).

Comment: What are the values Cd, cl, and S in these equations?

Comment: Coefficient of drag, C. of lift, and area.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} \rho V^2$ may only be used for incompressible dynamic flow, up to about M= 0.5.

Comment: @Koyovis: How is the relationship at higher speed?

Comment: Would you say control surfaces are still less effective due to the higher coefficients of lift and drag at higher speeds? At these speeds it takes less force from the control surfaces to turn, so couldn't it be argued to be more efficient at higher speeds? Does this make sense?

Comment: @SamJones: it really depends on how you want to measure efficiency. In my opinion lower lift and/or higher drag means (all the rest beings the same) less efficiency

Comment: The wiki article for dynamic pressure!

Comment: @Koyovis: in basic aerodynamic equations (like the one for L, D and M) all the effects due to "numbers" (Reynolds number, Mach number, Strouhal number, ... ) are condensed in the relevant coefficient (of lift, of drag, of moment) and the rest of the equation ($½\rho V²S$) remains the same. This is the beauty of dimensionless coefficients. 

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} \rho V^2$ is from the Bernoulli equation for **incompressible** flow. For compressible flow, the equation relevant to Mach number is used - everything changes a lot when the local M = 1 and beyond, right?

Comment: @Koyovis: "*$½ \rho V²$ is from Bernoulli equation*" **No**, it (and S as well) is from [Buckingham theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_%CF%80_theorem) and does not change. All the changes are concentrated in the relevant coefficient, which is indeed a function of Re and Ma

Comment: And therefore, professionals use the dynamic pressure equation with static pressure and Mach number $p_d = \frac {1}{2} \cdot \gamma \cdot p_{static} \cdot M^2$

Comment: @Koyovis: [Anderson](https://archive.org/details/FundamentalsOfAerodynamics5thEdition/page/n810/mode/1up) (but I don't know if he is professional enough for you...) uses the following equations for thin airfoils at subsonic and supersonic speeds respectively:

$\begin{cases}
L=½ \rho V² SC_l\rightarrow C_l=\frac{2\pi\alpha}{\sqrt{1-M²}}\\
L=½ \rho V² SC_l\rightarrow C_l=\frac{4\alpha}{\sqrt{M²-1}}
\end{cases}$

Comment: I'm familiar with linearised theory for thin airfoils at supersonic velocities.  Please focus on the dynamic pressure equation though, which was what the original comment was about. I'm through with this here.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is not true.

Control surface effectiveness scales with dynamic pressure.  Faster means more.

Shocks located on a control surface, or on the hinge line can wreak haovc.  However, once you're solidly supersonic, there is no 'divot' in the flow that the aircraft exists in.